# making a list with where/let clause Haskell

Tags: haskell, zip, tuples, list-comprehension, where-clause

I'm trying to make a list in haskell that has the second part of a tupple. I'm making the tuples inside the function however I'm not sure how to link those two (*zip* and the *list making*) so my function would work.

```
   search str goal = let letterPos =zip str [1..length(str)] in
      [snd(x) | x<-letterPos, fst(letterPos)==goal]
```

Basically this is how I create the tupples:

```
letterPos =zip str [1..length(str)]
```

and this is where I want to use them:

```
[snd(x) | x<-letterPos, fst(letterPos)==goal]
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It will be better if you add error you get.

Comment: don't use `length(str)` it is enough and more efficient `zip str [1..]` since you don't have to compute the length. Also, there is a built-in function call `findIndices` in the `Data.List` module which does exactly what you want

Comment: You might want to look at the `lookup` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `fst(letterPos)` with `fst(x)`.

Comment: Thank you so much :D I didn't realise that was the problem.

Comment: Or, better, with `fst x`. Parentheses are not used for function calls in Haskell.